# can not retrieve compressed bitmap from server

Tags: android, bitmap, compression, spring-boot, retrofit

So I am trying to store the byte[] array of a compressed bitmap through a rest server. I first retrieve the source file from the imageView and turn it into a Bitmap then turn it into the byte array, after that I send the raw bytes to the server and save it:

```
PhotoSvcApi photoService= RestServer.getInstance();
...
                            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)img.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                            byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();

                            Long newId = photoService.addPhotoData(imageBytes);
```

On the server side I use a springframe work to map the handlers to save and retrieve the data to the server. According to my logs and tests I am able to successfully save and retrieve the data from and to my client. Here is the method to retrieve the data from the server to the android client.

```
@RequestMapping(value = PhotoSvcApi.IMAGE_DATA_PATH, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    void getData(@PathVariable(value = PhotoSvcApi.ID_PARAMETER) Long id,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        byte[] source = imageData.get(id);

        try {
            response.getOutputStream().write(source);
        } catch ( IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

As you can see, I put the bytes in an OutputStream in the response body. Next, is where I believe the error happens as I am unable to successfully recreate the compressed bitmap. I am using retrofit to access the server.

```
public void getDataFromServer(long id){

        CallableTask.invoke(new Callable<Bitmap>() {

            @Override
            public Bitmap call() throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
                long giftId = intent.getLongExtra(ID_KEY, -1);
                Log.e("detail", String.valueOf(giftId));





                PhotoSvcApi photoService= RestServer.getInstance();
                Response response = photoService.getData(giftId); // retrofit streaming



                Bitmap bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response.getBody().in());
                if(bitmap == null){
                    Log.e("detail", "bitmap is in fact null - fix it");
                }
```

I really don't think its related to the server because my @post REST method sends the exact same amount of data that the @get method returns in its body

```
11-19 23:47:58.933: D/Retrofit(3405): ---> HTTP POST http://10.0.2.2:8080/giftdata
11-19 23:47:59.611: D/Retrofit(3405): ---> END HTTP (1701907-byte body)
11-19 23:48:07.081: D/Retrofit(3405): <--- HTTP 200 http://10.0.2.2:8080/giftdata (7474ms)
11-19 23:48:07.081: D/Retrofit(3405): : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
11-19 23:48:07.101: D/Retrofit(3405): <--- END HTTP (1-byte body)
...
11-19 23:48:54.324: D/Retrofit(3405): ---> HTTP GET http://10.0.2.2:8080/giftdata/4/data

11-19 23:48:54.332: D/Retrofit(3405): ---> END HTTP (no body)
11-19 23:48:54.372: D/Retrofit(3405): <--- HTTP 200 http://10.0.2.2:8080/giftdata/4/data (39ms)
11-19 23:48:54.372: D/Retrofit(3405): : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
11-19 23:48:57.671: D/Retrofit(3405): <--- END HTTP (1701907-byte body)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `@ResponseBody` on a void method, which doesn't really make any sense, but probably Spring is treating it literally and sending nothing. You shouldn't really have to write the bytes out to the response at all, just return them from the method.

Comment: Yes, apparently so. The bitmap is no longer returning null. Thank you. Now i just have to figure out why why imageView is not correctly displaying the bitmap.